# error when using typedef struct

Tags: c, struct, typedef

I have the following typedef struct

```
typedef unsigned int NOTE_FREQ;
/*******A_MUSIC_ELEMENT structure****************/ 
typedef struct { 
    NOTE_FREQ frequencyValue; 
    int duration; 
} A_MUSIC_ELEMENT;
```

Now I want to make an array of A_MUSIC_ELEMENT and with specific values.

```
A_MUSIC_ELEMENT ZTitleScreen[] = {{60, 20},{80, 50}};
```

and it compiles fine.  but to make things more readable I try to set

```
int BPM1 = 60;
int BPM2 = 80;
int TIME1 = 20;
int TIME2 = 50;
A_MUSIC_ELEMENT ZTitleScreen[] = {{BPM1, TIME1},{BPM2, TIME2}};
```

and i get an error saying :

```
constant expression required
```

i don't know why since it should be the same thing. i am using windows 8, mplab x IDE, hi tech c compiler.  any help to demystify this thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value of `BPM1` could change so the compiler won't allow it as an argument for the initializer list.

If you want to use named constants, try using `enum`.

Comment: In c++11 you have a features called `const_exp`, but in C you may be stuck with doing `HALF_NOTE` as a macro.

Answer (score 1):

6.7.9 Initialization

```
     4. All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static or 
thread storage duration shall be constant expressions or string literals.
```

Below are the different ways in which you can initialize a structure...

```
struct date date1= { 9, 5, 1982};           // Initializing structure
struct date date2 = { .day = 9, .month = 5};// Designated initializer
struct date date3 = {0};                    // Initializing all members to 0
struct date date4;
struct date date5 = date1;                  // Initialization using variable

date4.day = 9;      // Member wise initialization
date4.month = 5;    // Member wise initialization
date4.year = 1982;  // Member wise initialization
```

Comment: thanks. where is this from?  I only understand the main idea from this. all this static and thread storage stuff I would have to research to understand it

Comment: The above statement is from C standard (ISO/IEC 9899:201x). Below code I typed it.